# Text pattern matching in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching, textmatching

I have a scenario where I need to compare 2 texts and the based upon their pattern matching response should be binary ( True/False)

Examples:

when length is same

```
a = 231220
b = 231222

result = True
```

when pattern is same

```
a = `23/12/2018`
b = `01/03/2020'

result = True
```

when the pattern doesn't match

```
a = 0.90833333333
b = 0.3833333333333333

result = False
```

Is there a library in Python 3 to handle this kind of pattern matching ?
Or how can I handle this via python code

Comment: Which characters would you consider to define a pattern? Anything that isn't `A-Z`, `a-z` and `0-9`?

Comment: My loose suggestion would be to use some regex, but that is like asking for pain. If you do this, be ready.

Comment: Your pattern 3 seems to be based on length too.